# Certificate Based SSH Authentication still requires Private Key file

Tags: ssh, certificates

Most place I have read that should be able to login just with only the user certificate.
Testing a loopback login I have followed the following tutorial: https://goteleport.com/blog/how-to-configure-ssh-certificate-based-authentication/ and discovered I am misunderstanding a key concept:

```
You'll need both [the signed user certificate] and the private key for logging in.
```

I can't successfully `ssh` without the `id_rsa` key present alongside the `id_rsa-cert.pub` file. Within the certificate I've included `root` and personal user hence I can `ssh root@host` with no password which clearly uses the certificate as I have no key registration for root setup. It's using certificates registered in `/etc/`. Futhermore `ssh user@host` is successful without `known_hosts` or `authorized_keys` as I have in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/user-ca.pub
HostCertificate /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key-cert.pub
```

and in `Everywhere I have read that should be able to login just with the user certificate` the public key of the certificate authority in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`:

```
@cert-authority * $(</etc/ssh/host-ca.pub)
```

I was sure I've logged in without `id_rsa` present in the past. Can authentication be successful with only  the `~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub` file? If so what is this tutorial missing?

Comment: Maybe read through this page. I checked the one you linked and this has much more information and might get you set up correctly :) https://www.sobyte.net/post/2021-08/ssh-certificate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: you require **both** key `id_rsa` and certificate `id_rsa-cert.pub` for a certificate based authentication. The key is always required to encrypt the packets, certificate provides a 3rd party trusted identifier to the server.

> Both the user certificate and the private key it corresponds to are needed to log in. [OpenSSH Cookbook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Certificate-based_Authentication)

In this case the certificate permits you to login to a server you've never had prior knowledge of (you don't need your public key registered on the remote host's home directory's `authorized_keys` file) and the signing authority can provide time limits on the access or who you can masquerade as (`Principal` directive).

Answer (score 0):

With OpenSSH clients on Unix/Linux and MacOS you can remove the private key file after loading it into `ssh-agent`. If you're not using `ssh-agent` you have to keep the private key file because the cert file only contains the signed public key.

The OpenSSH client on Windows behaves differently because the `ssh-agent` is a specific reimplementation based on Windows` LSASS cache.

That's the reason why my [EKCA client](https://code.stroeder.com/EKCA/ekca-client) does not remove the private key file after loading it into `ssh-agent` if running on Windows. ([EKCA](https://ekca.stroeder.com/) is my own minimal solution for issuing short-term OpenSSH user certs.)